# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme in java 19 and jetty 9 (and Camel 3.20.4)

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, jks, pkcs#12

(Hope it's not a Camel specific question)

Hello,

I am migrating my app (Camel, Jetty) from java 8 to the newer java, which is currently:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 19.0.1+10-jvmci-22.3-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 19.0.1+10-jvmci-22.3-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I'm creating a p12 file using the following commands (taken from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/openssl-self-signed-cert)):

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout dela.key -x509 -days 36500 -out dela.crt`

`openssl pkcs12 -inkey dela.key -in dela.crt -export -out dela.p12`

However I'm getting this infamous error:

```
13:47:26.830 [qtp426394307-28] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection -- DecryptedEndPoint@53233b53{l=/127.0.0.1:8543,r=/127.0.0.1:36536,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=150/30000} stored flush exception
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:972)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:961)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1246)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:840)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:801)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1273)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
13:47:26.834 [qtp426394307-28] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection -- handshake failed SslConnection@79674fce::SocketChannelEndPoint@72db6307{l=/127.0.0.1:8543,r=/127.0.0.1:36536,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=125/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@79674fce{NEED_WRAP,eio=0/0,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@53233b53{l=/127.0.0.1:8543,r=/127.0.0.1:36536,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=153/30000}=>HttpConnection@770c0d41[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2d900990{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@7fc5f9be{s=HttpChannelState@667d6b12{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} {}
```

I see multiple advice around here but I'm struggling to understand how to apply it to my case.

1. I'm thinking my p12 keystore contains both public and private keys (saw it with "keystore explorer" advised somewhere)
2. I'm guessing I've used the correct rsa vs dsa algorithm as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854904/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-no-available-authentication-scheme)
3. I've tried to create a JKS from my p12 as it is said had helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067294/sslhandshakeexception-no-available-authentication-scheme) but to no avail.

I'm hoping adding something to the commands that create the keys and the keystore will fix the situation. What could it be or what am I doing wrong?

Along the verbose debug lines it prints something regarding the SSL, which is over my head, for example,

```
14:16:23.380 [qtp402249858-26] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.jsse.BaseSSLContextParameters -- SSLEngine [SSLEngine[hostname=127.0.0.1, port=48442, Session(1685963783380|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)]] created from SSLContext [javax.net.ssl.SSLContext@3fce8fd9].
14:16:23.381 [qtp402249858-26] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.jsse.BaseSSLContextParameters -- Configuring SSLEngine [SSLEngine[hostname=127.0.0.1, port=48442, Session(1685963783380|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)]] with 
     explicitly set cipher suites [null],
     cipher suite patterns [null],
     available cipher suites [[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]],
     currently enabled cipher suites [[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]],
     and default cipher suite patterns [Patterns [includes=[.*], excludes=[.*_NULL_.*, .*_anon_.*, .*_EXPORT_.*, .*_DES_.*, .*MD5, .*RC4.*]]].
     Resulting enabled cipher suites are [[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]].
14:16:23.381 [qtp402249858-26] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.jsse.BaseSSLContextParameters -- Configuring SSLEngine [SSLEngine[hostname=127.0.0.1, port=48442, Session(1685963783380|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)]] with 
     explicitly set protocols [null],
     protocol patterns [null],
     available protocols [[TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]],
     currently enabled protocols [[TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]],
     and default protocol patterns [Patterns [includes=[.*], excludes=[SSL.*]]].
     Resulting enabled protocols are [[TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]].
14:16:23.381 [qtp402249858-26] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory -- Customize SSLEngine[hostname=127.0.0.1, port=48442, Session(1685963783380|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)]
```

The similar code used to work with Jetty SSL when I was using Java 8 and Camel 2. Here is the snippet that configures the SSL, which, I believe, conforms with [the Camel's documentation on topic](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/jetty-component.html#_ssl_support_https) (the full program to test the error is [on github](https://github.com/fedd/cameljettyssl)):

```
            // ssl magik. doesn't work, but used to work on old java and camel
            File keyStoreFile = new File("dela.p12"); // also tried jks
            if (keyStoreFile.exists()) {
                String keystorePassword = "someSecretPassword";
                KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
                //ksp.setCamelContext(getContext());
                ksp.setResource(keyStoreFile.getPath());
                ksp.setPassword(keystorePassword);
                ksp.setType("pkcs12"); // also tried to use the default

                KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
                kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
                kmp.setKeyPassword("someSecretPassword");

                SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
                scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

                // add the SSL only to the secure jetty
                JettyHttpComponent jetty = getContext().getComponent(JETTY, JettyHttpComponent.class);
                jetty.setSslContextParameters(scp);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Konstantin Leboev https://github.com/realmfoo provided an answer: the keystore has to be created and then loaded from the file like this:

```
                // worked in Camel 2 but doesn't work now
                //ksp.setResource(keyStoreFile.getPath());
                //ksp.setPassword(keystorePassword);
                //ksp.setType("pkcs12"); // also tried to use the default
                
                // it works like this now
                KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
                try (var stream = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(keyStoreFile.getPath()))) {
                    ks.load(stream, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
                }
                ksp.setKeyStore(ks);
```

Comment: Well you can also define the appropriate system properties. This isn't the only way.